# JavaScript: If String Is Not A or B Then

Tags: javascript

How do I achieve this with a single `if` ? In other words, `if(fruit != "apple" || fruit != "orange"){` is not producing the expected result?

```
fruits.forEach(function(fruit){
  if(fruit != "apple"){ // < ----I want to use a compound OR, or compare multiple strings.
    if(fruit != "orange"){ // <---------I want this nested if gone.
      console.log(fruit + " is not apple or orange [two]");
    }
  }
});
```

```js
const fruits = ["apple","orange","banana","cherry"];

fruits.forEach(function(fruit){
  if(fruit != "apple"){
    console.log(fruit + " is not apple");
  }
});

fruits.forEach(function(fruit){ //<------- this is what I'm having problems with
  if(fruit != "apple" || fruit != "orange"){
    console.log(fruit + " is not apple or orange [one]");
  }
});

fruits.forEach(function(fruit){
  if(fruit != "apple"){
    if(fruit != "orange"){
      console.log(fruit + " is not apple or orange [two]");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: You want *and*, not *or*.  If fruit is not apple, then it might be orange, so "if it's not an apple or not an orange" will always be true.

Comment: Nasty. That && does work doesn't it...

Comment: `!(A || B)` is basically the same as `(!A) && (!B)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Pointy *points* out that:

```js
const fruits = ["apple","orange","banana","cherry"];

fruits.forEach(function(fruit){
  if(fruit != "apple"){
    console.log(fruit + " is not apple");
  }
});

fruits.forEach(function(fruit){ //<------- this is what I'm having problems with
  if(fruit != "apple" && fruit != "orange"){ // notice
    console.log(fruit + " is not apple or orange [one]");
  }
});

fruits.forEach(function(fruit){
  if(fruit != "apple"){
    if(fruit != "orange"){
      console.log(fruit + " is not apple or orange [two]");
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One liners?

```js
const fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'cherry'];
fruits
  .filter(f => f !== 'apple' && f !== 'orange')
  .forEach(f => console.log(`${f} is nor apple nor orange`));

// alternatively
fruits
  .filter(f => !['apple', 'orange'].includes(f))
  .forEach(f => console.log(`${f} is nor apple nor orange`));
```

Comment: I prefer to doing so because it's more readable, however I did not choice it because changing into that style may confuse OP to where to change.